# Ошибка в формировании GET запроса

Tags: php, post, get

Пытаюсь отправить платежную форму на сервер Payeer

```
<form method="post" action="https://payeer.com/merchant/">
<input type="hidden" name="m_shop" value="418623174">
<input type="hidden" name="m_orderid" value="32423">
<input type="hidden" name="m_amount" value="100.00">
<input type="hidden" name="m_curr" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="m_desc" value="YWRtaW4=">
<input type="hidden" name="m_sign" value="61745F8CCB42E8DFF6B4031989E4AD193DEBF3508A2040715C930CC2258CB2C1">
<input type="hidden" name="m_params" value="EvagwG5GmhmsIJHPKhELeCgEon4O63tSack16GuInIE%3D">
 <input type="submit" value="send" />
```

Это работает хорошо, но если я пытаюсь сформировать GET запрос я получаю ошибку

```
https://payeer.com/merchant/?m_shop=418623174&m_orderid=32423&m_amount=100.00&m_curr=USD&m_desc=YWRtaW4=&m_sign=61745F8CCB42E8DFF6B4031989E4AD193DEBF3508A2040715C930CC2258CB2C1&m_params=EvagwG5GmhmsIJHPKhELeCgEon4O63tSack16GuInIE%3D
```

Почему так происходит и где я допускаю ошибку?

Благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Может потому что payeer принимает только POST запросы к мерчанту?

Comment: Нет, GET тоже работают, пример https://payeer.com/merchant/?m_shop=373439493&m_orderid=1&m_amount=1.00&m_curr=RUB&m_desc=YWRtaW4=&m_sign=D8DA10E2BB3F8C4CB3D17A375E73B47756E7DCAC6A504E86CC58714A267097BA

Comment: Что у вас в `m_params` делает `%3D`? Это вы пытаетесь символ `=` передать?

Comment: Это зашифрованный параметр 'submerchant' => 'mail.com', $m_params = urlencode(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCR YPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, json_encode($arParams), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));

Comment: Попробуйте в пути (action) убрать последний слэш. Возможно поэтому не работает

Comment: Не помогло, к сожалению

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При отправке формы методом GET необходимо параметр m_params обернуть url_encode()